# Angular.js filterable list with predefined values by a select field and a clickable map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, list, select, filtering

Hope someone could help me out with this. Basically Im having a a list of results, that I have to be able to filter by a Select field, with predefined 'region' values, AND a clickable SVG map (contains A tags with #region_values), values on the map & the Select field will be the same. Been browsing the web for hours, without finding anything useful.

How can I attach both for the same list as a filter?

Here is the list generator (working properly):

```
<div class="results" id="goto" ng-controller="listCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="filterText" />
    <div class="list">
        <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items">
            <div class="columns image">
                <img src="images/misc/{{ item.image }}" alt="{{ item.name }}">
                <a target="_blank" class="button green-button" href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.button }}</a>
            </div>
            <div class="columns copy">
                <div class="result"><span class="place">{{ $index+1 }}</span>{{ item.vote }} de los votos</div>
                <h2>{{ item.name }}</h2>
                <p>{{ item.desc }}</p>
                <p>{{ item.region }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the controller :

```
function listCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.items = [{
            "name": "City Name",
            "desc": "City Description",
            "vote": "56,4%",
            "image": 'image.jpg',
            "url": 'http://sample.url',
            "button": "Button Text",
            "region": "Some Region"
        }
    ];
}
```

Map is like :

```
<svg>
    <g>
        <a id="s40" xlink:href="#region1">
            <path> ...</path>
        </a>
        <a id="s40" xlink:href="#region2">
            <path> ...</path>
        </a>
    </g>
</svg>
```

And the Select :

```
<select>
   <option value="region1">Region1</option>
   <option value="region2">Region2</option>
</select>
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually solved by adding ng-click="catFilter='regionname'" to the links that I wanted to control the select field with the desired region name.

Answer (score 0):

Searching and filtering from text box.   and this pulnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/EjzcOG?p=preview will help

> HTML

```
<label>
 Search Text: <input ng-model="val" ng-keyup="search(val)" ng-keydown="search(val)">
</label><br>
<div data-ng-repeat="customer in displayCustomers">
<span>{{customer}}</span>
```

> Script

```
$scope.customers = ['bob', 'sean', 'rocky', 'john', 'ali', 'isak', 'isthiqui', 'ram', 'acheer', 'shrish'];

 $scope.displayCustomers = $scope.customers;

 $scope.search = function (searchTerm) {
            $scope.displayCustomers = $filter('filter')($scope.customers, searchTerm);
};
```

Comment: Thanks but as Title says : SELECT AND Clickable map filter, not Textbox!

Comment: select word from select and clickable map select the vale and pass it to search method it will filter.